# Resolving ambiguity in an interface which extends two other interfaces which have a method with the same name

Tags: c#, interface

if I have interfaces:

```
public interface ANewThing { IKey Key { get; } }

public interface AnOldThing { object Key{ get; } }

public interface ACompositeThing : ANewThing , AnOldThing  { }
```

and I write this:

```
ACompositeThing compositeThing = GetCompositeThing();  
Trace.WriteLine(compositeThing.Key);
```

it doesn't compile, complaining that the call to `Key` is ambiguous (it doesn't make any difference if the type returned by the `Key` property is the same).  I am aware that in the class implementing `ACompositeThing` I can explicitly implement the interfaces `ANewThing` and `AnOldThing`, but this doesn't help me when I have methods which don't know about the concrete implementations and only know that they will be given `ACompositeThing`.

So my question is:

Can I do anything in the `ACompositeThing` interface to say how the `Key` property ambiguity should be resolved?

Like say 'when accessing the `Key` property through this interface, always return the `Key` property from the `ANewThing` implementation'?

Or do I have to accept that I can't do this and must always cast my `ACompositeThing` to one of the other interfaces before I do the access?

Comment: What does the implementation of whatever `GetCompositeThing` returns look like?

Comment: but where's the class that implements `ACompositeThing` ?

Comment: @AakashM @vukanino the implementation is irrelevant in this case, I want to know how I deal with this issue when I have an interface only.  Lets say that some third parties provides all the implementations of `ACompositeThing` and I have a library that only deals with the `ACompositeThing` interfaces and that concrete implementations are always passed to the library so it cannot know anything about them.

Comment: The point is that when `ACompositeThing` is implemented, you *have* to make (at least) one of the `Key`s use explicit implementation, since you can't have `IKey Key{}` and `object Key{}` as two members. Therefore a decision has already been made about what `Key` means, by the time you come to consume `ACompositeThing`.

Comment: ReSharper's suggestion is to rename one of the Key properties.

Comment: @AakashM there is no Key property on `ACompositeThing` there is only `ANewThing.Key` and `AnOldThing.Key` one can be 'the default' for a particular implementation which will be chosen when accessing through the **Class** and the other will be accessible explicitly through the other interface, but when accessing through the `ACompositeThing` interface the compiler can't know which interfaces method you want to call.

Comment: @brgerner yeah, unfortunately renaming the property is not an option for me.

Comment: Ah I see, no matter which one the impl tries to elevate to public, the compiler still isn't happy accessing `Key` through the interface. Got you.

Comment: @AakashM :) the default answer to this seems to be for everyone to shout 'explicit interface implementation' (which is what happened in the other answers in similar veins I found), but this doesn't solve the issue of accessing through the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nasty, but you can declare *another* member in `ACompositeThing`:

```
public interface ACompositeThing : ANewThing , AnOldThing {
    new IKey Key { get; }
}
```

Now that will take preference from the *caller's* point of view. However, it means there are now potentially *three* different implementations - and any `ACompositeThing` implementation which uses explicit interface implementation for `ANewThing.Key` will *either* have to change to expose the member publicly, or add a new member to implement `ACompositeThing.Key`.

Of course if you *possibly* can, you should avoid this - or only use it in a transition from an old interface to a new interface for a very limited time.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  This is exactly what I wanted to know, just what my options are.  We have an older library that used to use objects as Keys and have moved to using IKey implementations as keys in a newer library, but I have an object that needs to implement interfaces from both libraries and this is currently an issue.  We could update the old library but are not sure we want to do this just yet, as this would be a breaking change.  This gives us an option of a stop gap.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

More a workaround than an answer: Make ACompositeThing to be a base class (instead of an interface) that explicitly implements the Key property.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do anything in the ACompositeThing interface to say how the Key property ambiguity should be resolved?
>
> Like say 'when accessing the Key property through this interface, always return the Key property from the ANewThing implementation'?

Try this code:

```
ANewThing newThing = GetCompositeThing();  
Trace.WriteLine(newThing.Key);
```

or

```
ACompositeThing compositeThing = GetCompositeThing();  
Trace.WriteLine(((ANewThing)compositeThing).Key);
```

Comment: thanks, I was aware of this as I said in my question: 'Or do I have to accept that I can't do this and must always cast my ACompositeThing to one of the other interfaces before I do the access?'

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem called "Diamond problem" or "Diamond inheritance".
In most cases it arises from bad OOP design or bad naming conventions. I think this is your problem, too.

Try to google "Diamond problem" a little, there are various solutions.

Comment: This is bullshit. The "Diamond problem" is the 1) **re**convergence of 2) classes. Here, we have convergence of interfaces, which is a different thing of different things.